# ruby gsub with condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to replace a value from a dropdown if multiple conditions are met. I'm trying to do this with the gsub method.

[image]

scenario 1: if current selected value is 9.3.9 then value 9.4.1 should not be available

scenario 2:
if current selected value is 9.3.10 then value 9.4.1 and 9.4.4 should not be available

Sorry for not including the code snippet. Below is the method I use to get my RDS instances. I already use gsub to check if the current version used is 9.3 and prevent an upgrade to 9.4. I want to change that to the scenario above.

```
    def available_engine_versions(instance)
      if instance.engine == RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_MYSQL
        # This custom override for certain MySQL cases suppresses the option to upgrade to 5.6 from 5.5.
        # Amazon cannot do direct updates from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6 for DBs created before 4/23/2014.
        # instance.instance.created_at -> Uses Amazon's date of creation, not the one stored by ActiveRecord
        if instance.nil? || instance.engine_version.start_with?('5.6.') || instance.instance.nil? || instance.instance.created_at >= Time.parse('2014-04-23')
          RdsConfiguration::rds_configurations[RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_MYSQL][:engine_versions]
        else
          RdsConfiguration::rds_configurations[RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_MYSQL][:engine_versions].select{ |type| type.to_f <= 5.5 }
        end
      elsif instance.engine == RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_POSTGRES
        RdsConfiguration::rds_configurations[RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_POSTGRES][:engine_versions].select{ |type| type.gsub(/(\d+\.\d+).*?$/,"\\1") == instance.engine_version.gsub(/(\d+\.\d+).*?$/,"\\1") } # no upgrades from e.g. 9.3.x to 9.4.y
      else
        RdsConfiguration::rds_configurations[instance.engine][:engine_versions]
      end
    end
```

Comment: how are you storing the list of versions & the selected version?  need to see some code to provide an answer; e.g., gsub is a string operator but I would expect you are actually checking an array

Comment: This seems like a JavaScript problem. Are you sure you need Ruby to do this?

Comment: You also probably want to sort those "versionabetically" rather than in the default sort order: `sort_by { |v| v.split.collect(&:to_i) }`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How are you populating the array? As @tadman says, this is a javascript problem, since the user selection change is a client side operation.

Comment: Please show your code for the view.  Also show your code for any Javascript that you have associated with this.

Comment: This is not a javascript problem. I'm looking for a different logic in the method  only to show the compatible upgrade versions available. I added the method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
selected_value = instance.engine_version.gsub(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*?$/,"\\1")
RdsConfiguration::rds_configurations[RdsGeneric::RDS_TYPE_POSTGRES][:engine_versions].reject do |type|
  dropdown_entry = type.gsub(/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*?$/,"\\1")

  (dropdown_entry == "9.4.1" && selected_value == "9.3.9") || (["9.4.1", "9.4.4"].include?(dropdown_entry) && selected_value == "9.3.10")
end
```

Notice that I changed `select` to `reject`.

Knowing what the data looks like would help a lot. You may not need the gsub at all now.

Comment: The data is just version numbers pulled via the aws API so its format is consistent e.g. 9.3.x etc. gsub was used to hide the newer versions  (9.4.x etc.)  of the engine options if the 9.3 version was currently in use. I would still like to match the data format if possible. But you are correct, maybe gsub is overkill. I would love to hear your suggestion.

Comment: I know you can simply remove the gsub and do a straight comparison but I would like to make sure the format is consistent (at least from my end).

Comment: BTW, thanks for your suggestion above it worked. ;-)